# Notation in stochastic integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

There are some notation I don't understand:
Given $W_t$, $n$-dimensional Brownian motion, and a smooth function $u:R^n\to R$
my book asserts:

$$E^x\left[u(W_0)\right]=u(x)$$

What is the notation $E^x$? what kind of expectation is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E^x$ is the expectation under the path measure of $W(\cdot)$ started at $W(0) = x$.

> Example: $E^x[W(t)] = E^x[W(t)-W(0)+W(0)] = E^x[W(t)-W(0)] + x = x$ since $W(t)-W(0) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$.

In plain English, $E^x$ is just ordinary expectation with the understanding that the starting point of BM is a variable, $x$.

Comment: in starting point you mean that W_0=x?

Comment: @Lin Yes, exactly.